# Inheritence doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

So I've got 3 files for my hoemwork assignment, this question dosen't relate to the assignment, but trying to figure out why the code I'm suppose to use as the bassis for my assignment is not compiling correctly.

So first there's an abstract class (linkedListType) in the file ( linkedList.h ), which can be found here: >http://pastebin.com/STGHvdDs>

Then the class unorderedLinkList inherits from that (in the file unorderedLinkedList.h), which can be found here http://pastebin.com/yyv5vT7i

There are no seperate .cpp files, everything is in the .h file for those.

When I compile the main/test program (just to see what errors I'll get before I even begin the assignment) I get lots of errors similar to this:

**unorderedLinkedList.h: In member function ‘bool unorderedLinkedList::search(const Type&) const’:
unorderedLinkedList.h:46: error: ‘first’ was not declared in this scope
unorderedLinkedList.h: In member function ‘void unorderedLinkedList::insertFirst(const Type&)’:
unorderedLinkedList.h:66: error: ‘first’ was not declared in this scope***

They all revolve around that ('not declared in scope').

Someone suggested using the linkedListType:: access approach to the variables (which are defined as private in linkedListType), but that didn't do anything to help this problem.

Help, please, so I can hurry up and actually do the parts of my homework I can't do until I know why this isn't working.  So you don't htink I"m trying to get you to do my homework for me: my homework is to write several methods given by the professor to manipulate the linked lists.

Thanks!

Comment: Mmmm.. can you also post your `main`?

Comment: The questions to be posted here are meant to be self-contained! Learn to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Captain Oblivious <http://stackoverflow.com/users/845568/captain-obvlious> answered it, I accidntally flagged it, rather than accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you try to access the name `first` as an independent name which is not found in the scope: class templates do *not* look into templated base classes to find names unless the name is made a dependent name. Non-dependent names are resolved during phase I look-up at which point the base class is unknown (it could be specialized to have an entirely different layout). Dependent names are looked up during phase II look-up.

Thus, you need to make the name `first` a dependent name using, e.g.,

1. `this->first`
2. `linkedListType<T>::first`

My personal preference is to use `this->` as this nicely takes care of stating what is actually meant and it also doesn't need to be changed if the location of the member changes.

Answer (score 1):

Prepend the variables that are causing the problems with this-> 
Captain Oblivious https://stackoverflow.com/users/845568/captain-obvlious should get credit for that answer, and I am indebted to him, but I accidentally deleted his answer rather than clicking accept (saved my laptop from the coffee though).